# How can I do this query to fetch records?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to fetch records from the table "blogs" that was written in the history of the past week and be of the highest viewing figures in order.

I did this query :

```
@most_viewed = DB[:blogs].where(:date <(Time.now - 7), :views > 900).reverse_order(:id).limit(0..9).sort(:views)
```

Comment: Please give your table structure of that db[:blogs] with data type...

Comment: what DB adapter you are using ? What is your ORM name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the [documentation of Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html):

```
@most_viewed = DB[:blogs].where{ date <(Time.now - 7) }.where { views > 900 }.order(Sequel.desc(:id)).limit(10)
```

Or

```
@most_viewed = DB[:blogs].where{ date <(Time.now - 7) }.where { views > 900 }.order(:views).limit(10)
```

Depending on whether you want to order by `id` or by `views` (in your code you seem to want to do both...)

Comment: I want to gave records from 7 days ago how can I do that ?

Comment: how about `.where{ date.to_date == (Time.now.to_date - 7) }`?

Comment: Thank you , I was do that `.where{ date > (Time.now - 604800) }`

604800 = 60*60*24

7 days by second